# angular, element.bind specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I-m trying to create a custom directive, and bind it a specific div, however, I only can bind it to input, any way to bind it for divs?

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs) { 

     element.bind('input', function(e) {}); // works perfectly
     element.bind('#myDiv', function(e) {}); //does not work!

}
```

Comment: yes and yes, any other requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `.bind` methods needs, the element on which you want to bind an event should be there on left on side

```
angular.element('#myDiv').bind('click', function(e) {});
```

Basically `.bind` method takes an `eventType`, `eventData` & `eventHandler`

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )
```

The code which you are saying working perfectly should not work.

Comment: what exactly is this eventData?